# Как указать что класс может состоять из самого себя?

Tags: java

1. Есть монитор, мышь, блок питания, системный блок, компьютер и т.д.
2. Все это продукты, которые можно продать по отдельности либо вместе.

Пример:

a. блок питания, видеокарта входят в состав системного блока, который можно продать. Также можно продать по отдельности блок питания, видеокарту

b. системный блок который состоит из видеокарты и блока питания тоже может являться частью "компьютера" который можно также продать.

В итоге выделяю класс:

```
public class Product{
   String name;
   String type;
   double[] ParamList;
```

Пример:

Product

- Мышь
- Периферия
- Черная

Вопрос как указать что класс Product может состоять из самого себя? Причем в глубину несколько раз: Клавиатура->Системный Блок->Компьютер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и объявляйте

```
public class Product {
   String name;
   String type;
   double[] ParamList;
   Product nested;
}
```

или

```
public class Product {
   String name;
   String type;
   double[] ParamList;
   Product[] nested;
}
```

или

```
public class Product {
   String name;
   String type;
   double[] ParamList;
   List<Product> nested;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Создать абстрактный класс Product. Остальные классы(Mouse, Keyboard и т.д) наследуют от него общие свойства такие как String name; String type; double price; и т.п.

a. Класс, представляющий системный  SystemUnit:

```
class SystemUnit extends product{

   private PowerSupply powerSupply; // объект класса, представляющий блок питания
   private VideoCard videoCard;  // объект класса, представляющий видео карту

}
```

b. Класс, представляющий компьютер:

```
class Computer {
   privare SystemUnit systenUnit;
   .............................
}
```